Why isn't my boxplot on r studio isn't showing up?
The boxplot isn't showing up at all, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is the code that most of the information was given to us. The other information was taken from a provide data set call DDT.csv that.
      boxplot(dfsp$LENGTH, col = "blue", 
      pch = 21, bg = "red", 
      main = paste("Boxplot of LENGTH for", xsp), 
      ylab = "LENGTH")


Could be related to this issue. If it is, the solution is to install this patch.

Do you get an error in the console when executing the code?
